# Ajax Issues making a post request for my join table full

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

To the point: 422 error making a post request for my join table using ajax on the front end.

I'm creating an app for a fullstack project using rails (as my api) and ajax to make my api request to my routes.  I have three tables on my back end (users: :email, :token, :password_digest),(fantasy_players: :player_id, :user_id, :target), and (players: :name, :team, :bye)

On my front end i can make a successful post to my players table and my curl requests to my back end seem to work fine for my fantasy_players table.  I'm receiving a 422 unprocessable entity, the server code reads as follows :

```
Started POST "/fantasy_players" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-12-02 19:29:38 -0500
Processing by FantasyPlayersController#create as */*
  Parameters: {"submit"=>"Add To My Players", "player"=>{"id"=>"1"}, "fantasy_player"=>{"target"=>"yes"}}
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."token" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["token", "92ed3b66f0608a14b0225cad5a362027"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
[active_model_serializers] Rendered ActiveModel::Serializer::Null with ActiveModel::Errors (0.41ms)
Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 8ms (Views: 2.7ms | ActiveRecord: 0.6ms)
```

### front end events:

```
    const onAddUserPlayer = function (event) {
      event.preventDefault()
      const data = getFormFields(this)
      console.log(data)
      api.addUserPlayer(data)
        .then(ui.addUserPlayerSuccess)
        .catch(ui.addUserPlayerFailure)
    }
```

### api call

```
    const addUserPlayer = function (data) {
      return $.ajax({
      url: config.apiOrigin + '/fantasy_players',
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        Authorization: 'Token token=' + store.user.token
        },
        data
      })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's [`CSRF`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#csrf-countermeasures) issue.

The layout which is rendering this corresponding view, should contain this:

```
<%= csrf_meta_tag %>
```

And it adds CSRF token to your view header, so you can get it easily from frontend using something like: `$('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')`.

In your case try to add `beforeSend` to you `ajax` request. Maybe something like:

```
beforeSend: function(xhr) {xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'))},
```

Cheers!

Comment: I appreciate the help .... the biggest issue here is that im new at this and i'm still learning how to ask the right questions while supplying the proper information.  My problem was that I was passing name="player[id]" in with my input on html.  I needed to pass it the object through my join table like so <input type="text" name='fantasy_player[player_id]'  .... I appreciate you taking the time to help!